# If power is an homomorphism then the image is a normal group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have the following problem:
Let G be a group and $n$ such that $f(x) = x^n$ is an homomorphism. Then, $Im(f)$ is a normal subgroup. How can I demonstrate this?

Comment: What are you struggling with? Showing it's a subgroup, or showing that it's normal?

Comment: @user1729 Showing that it’s normal, as far as i know the image of an homomorphism is always a subgroup

Comment: Ok, great. Do you know that $(gxg^{-1})^n=gx^ng^{-1}$? You just need to stare at this for a while, and understand why this is in the image.

Comment: @user1729 So the proof would be something like this: let $x^n \in Im(f)$ and $g \in G$
$g x^n g^{-1} = (gxg^{1})^n \in Im f$, therefore $Im f$ is normal?

Comment: Essentially, yes. You should type this up and post it as an answer, just to make sure you understand everything!